# Determine if the set of all $f$ with $f(1) = 1 + f(0)$ is a real linear spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the exercise 1.5 -  5 from Apostol' Calculus, vol 2. The answer is no. Why?

Comment: you mean that the set of such $f$ forms a linear space?

Comment: Yes. I changed the title now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just show that the set $F = \{ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid f(1) = 1 + f(0)\}$ is not closed under addition of elements. Therefore, it's not a linear space over the reals:

Suppose $f_1, f_2 \in F$. Let $g$ be the map $g = f_1 + f_2$. Then $$ g(1) = f_1(1) + f_2(1) = 2 + f_1(0) + f_2(0) = 2+g(0) \not= 1+g(0), $$ which means that $g$ does not satisfy the property $g(1) = 1+g(0)$, so $g \not\in F$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ both satisfy the condition, then what is $(f+g)(1)$? Can you show it's not equal to $1+(f+g)(0)$?